# Is there support for variadic functions in ATS?

Tags: ats

Probably the most famous variadic function is `printf` in C, which can take an variable number of arguments. Is there a way to assign a type to `printf` in ATS? In general, can variadic functions be typed in ATS?

Answer (score 2):

Some work was done to accomplish this around the time of the ATS2 0.3.8 release. A simple example of a typed variadic function in ATS is found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/master/doc/EXAMPLE/TESTATS/variadic.dats).

By mimicking this example, yes, one can have typed variadic functions in ATS. Currently, however, it appears that unpacking the list of variadic arguments within ATS code itself is not possible. In the example linked above, we use inline C code to get around this limitation.